# Text not vertical aligning within a DIV

Tags: html, css

I cannot work out why the browser is not allowing me to set a margin-top or padding-top on a DIV to allow me to center the text.

HTML -

```
<div id="header">           
    <div id="Nav">
        <div id="navright">
            <a href="#">Home</a>
            <a href="#">About Us</a>
                <a href="#">Contact Us</a>
            <a href="#">Find Us</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS -

```
#nav {
    width: auto;
    position: relative;
}

#nav a {
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: "Arial";
    font-size: 14pt;
    color: #ffffff;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

Result -

[image: Screenshot of the misaligned text within a DIV]

Any ideas where I am going wrong? Thanks

Comment: Add `display: block` to `#nav a {`

Comment: The result you posted (the image) is not the same as the one that is actually produced by your code. And CSS selectors are case-sensitive, so `#nav` is not equal to `#Nav`.

Comment: Also, be caution about margin collapse when using margin.

Comment: provide all the code.. through jsfiddle.net is good...

Comment: How is the result not the same as my code? I have corrected the case with no success. When adding display: block to the #nav, it still does not work.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Anusha_Mallajosyula/geP2K/  this is how it looks...

Comment: You have to specify height of the div, or it shrinks to size of its content, so you cant set margin or padding of its content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are writing Nav nog nav

Html code should be:

`<div id="nav">` not `<div id="Nav">`

Thats why your css doesn't work on the `div`

And use `line-height` for your `a`

```
#nav a {
  line-height: (pixel height of the li or nav);
}
```

**Working [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7kM4m/) here**

Answer (score 1):

try to add `display:inline-block;` in you links

```
#nav a { 
    ...
    display:inline-block;
}
```

and rename `<div id="Nav">` to `<div id="nav">`

Answer (score 0):

add `display: inline-block;` to your a tag

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xZxx4/)

and obviously correct your typo Nav to nav.

Answer (score 0):

```
#nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: "Arial";
    font-size: 14pt;
    color: #ffffff;
    position: relative;
    height:25px;
    line-height:25px;
    margin:5px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the `margin-top` to appear you'll have to declare `display: inline-block` for the `<a>` elements, as someone already pointed out. If you want the text to be vertically centered, though, you could also work with something like `line-height: 50px;`.
Here's [a fiddle to play with](http://jsfiddle.net/7Ey4H/).
And you should of course correct the misspelling of your CSS selector or the HTML `id` attribute as mentioned by several users.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
display:inline-block
```

in `#nav a`

Answer (score 0):

just add `line-height` as same as the height of your nav `<div>`

And do correct the typo error.

eg:

```
#nav {height:20px; float:left;}
#nav a {line-height:20px;}
```